# $('selector').editableSelect() correct way get value editableSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, select

*My jsp *

```
<script>
let advSearchTitleForBookId;

$(function () {
  $('#sBook').editableSelect();

   $('#sBook')
            .editableSelect()
            .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
               advSearchTitleForBookId=li.val()
               alert(advSearchTitleForBookId)
            });

});

</script>

<div class="advEntityClass editableSelectClass"><label for="sBook">Title</label>
        <select id="sBook" class="editable-select">
            <c:forEach var="bl" items="${bookList}">
                <option value="${bl.id}">${bl.title}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select></div>
```

*I get id, but then get **VM1388:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined* error* *

http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/ used!

Comment: make sure the dom has loaded by using window.onload in your script.

Comment: check if `li` is `null`/`undefined` before using `li.val()`

Comment: As this is a jquery/js question, can you provide the html as rendered, then convert (it can be converted) to a snippet.

Comment: You're calling `.editableSelect()` twice on the same element - no idea if that's an issue, but the examples in your link only call it once.  Worth checking.

Comment: @freedomn how check, i cannot. I used alert- because check to get id. if i write alert same error get

Comment: `if (li != undefined) ...`  [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: @freedomn thanks! But i do not get error, but advSearchTitleForBookId-value is undifined

Comment: *"I get error cannot read property"* ... *"I do not get error"* - which is it?  Perhaps you could make a snippet to demonstrate the issue.  See [mcve].